# JavaScript - Dynamically Moving multiple markers on google map without duplications

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I am showing multiple marker on Google map using below code in which `finalArray2` is containing multiple latitude and longitude. `finalArray2` also changed dynamically to show movement of multiple marker.

```
    for (let key in finalArray2) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(finalArray2[key][0], finalArray2[key][1]),
          map: map,
          marker_id: key
          });
}
```

Above code is showing duplicate marker and 
I am trying to remove marker by using

```
marker.setMap(null)
```

But the problem is it is removing all the marker.

I don't know where to put this marker remove code.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is when creating the markers push it to a new array as well as creating the position as an object before hand. Might I also suggest that you also rather put your data in a object array. Example:

```
markerData = [
   {
   key: "key",
   position {
   lat: LAT,
   lng: LNG 
   }
}
]

let markers = [];
markerData.foreach(mark) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: mark.position,
      map: map,
      marker_id: mark.key
          });
      markers.push(marker);
}
```

Then have a separate function which receives the marker object and sets its map to null. Maybe even have two separate functions one for removing a single marker and one to remove all.
Single:

```
function removeMarker(marker) {
  marker.setMap(null)
}
```

All:

```
function removeAllMarkers() {
   markers.foreach(marker => {
      removeMarker(marker);
});
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get the requirement. Do you have any example or sample code?

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) is a link to the marker documentation on google.

Comment: If I my ask what is this for?

Comment: its for real time location tracking via firebase

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:Dynamically Moving multiple markers on google map without duplications of markers

```
var index=0;
    for (let key in finalArray2) {
    if(marker[index] != null){
     marker[index]=setMap(null);

    }
          marker[index] = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(finalArray2[key][0], finalArray2[key][1]),
              map: map,
              marker_id: key
              });
    index++;

    }
```